# im trying to display text after clicking a button on flutter, its a sign up page

Tags: flutter

```
      Positioned(
        left: 150.0,
        top: 630.0,
        right: null,
        bottom: null,
        width: 100.0,
        height: 50.0,
        child: Align(
  child: RaisedButton(
    child: Text(
      'Confirm',
      style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20.0),
    ),
    color: Color.fromARGB(255, 227, 236, 246),
    textColor: Color.fromARGB(255, 49, 69, 106),
    padding: EdgeInsets.all(5.0),
    onPressed: () {
      for(int i=0; i<usernames.length; i++){
        if(conEmail.text.isEmpty | conName.text.isEmpty | conUsername.text.isEmpty | conPassword.text.isEmpty | conConfirm.text.isEmpty ){
        print("some fields are empty");
        break;

      }
```

instead of printing 'some fields are empty' I would like to create a text to pop up on the signup page displaying that same message.
[screen layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ydciI.png)

Answer (score 0):

Based on your code excerpt, I'm guessing the UI is in a stateful widget. You can show an alert popup or show the text on the signup page. The best solution, in my opinion is to group the entries in a Form widget.

The documentation has example code: [Form widget API and example](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Form-class.html)

If that doesn't fit your needs and you want to show the error message on the signup page itself, you can include the error message as a text that is optionally visible. This means you have to have a boolean value showing if the entries are complete.

````
```
bool formIsOk = true;
String errorString = '';
...
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  RaisedButton(...
      onPressed: () {
  for(int i=0; i<usernames.length; i++){
    if(conEmail.text.isEmpty | conName.text.isEmpty | conUsername.text.isEmpty | conPassword.text.isEmpty | conConfirm.text.isEmpty ){
    errrorString = 'some fields are empty';
    break;
  }
  if (!errorString.isEmpty) {
    setState(() {
     }
    );
  }
...
//other widgets
...
Visibility(visible: errorString.isEmpty, 
  child: Text('some fields are empty'))

```
````

Finally, if you just want to pop up an alert, you can use the [AlertDialog class](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/AlertDialog-class.html) using showDialog:

````
```
onPressed: () => onPressed() {
  for(int i=0; i<usernames.length; i++){
    if(conEmail.text.isEmpty | conName.text.isEmpty | conUsername.text.isEmpty | conPassword.text.isEmpty | conConfirm.text.isEmpty ){
showDialog<String>(
    context: context,
    builder: (BuildContext context) => AlertDialog(
      title: const Text('ValidationError'),
      content: const Text('Some fields are empty'),
      actions: <Widget>[
        TextButton(
          onPressed: () => Navigator.pop(context, 'OK'),
          child: const Text('OK'),
        ),
      ],
    ),
  }
```
````

Answer (score 0):

Instead of *print("some fields are empty");* call *showDialog()* with a message.